# Please, Identify the Ated Als

Tags: cryptic-clues, poetry, connect-wall

> I seek his crypt and come to visit
> the site of Humpty's fated falls
> where definitions aren't explicit.
> But as with most awaited walls,
> connect the groups and you won't miss it.
> Please, identify the Ated Als.

- Gangster in a bus (4)
- Opposite of writing everything twice about object oriented programming (6)
- Iron fifty nine (5)
- Woman that is five empty liters (6)
- Red flag I mixed up (8)
- Channel Island has the queen instead of Stack Exchange (5)
- Electroacoustic transducer and lock opener (6)
- Nickel in a quarry (6)
- A poem about me (4)
- Oscar followed Lily’s cousin back without me (5)
- Err; go wrong (5)
- At first I protected princesses in heaven (6)
- Crazy, nosy OP (6)
- He messed with Trump (7)
- Odd things go eery (6)
- Beginning of the other mother (3)

Comment: What's the character at the beginning of "Iron fifty nine"? It seems to be the box character for me.

Comment: @justhalf sorry, it was some stray character that wasn't visible to me. Perhaps an artifact of copying and pasting from macOS Notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These "Ated Als" are actually

> A**nima**ted A**nima**ls!

Each of these is

> a cryptic clue, except without a definition. The clues' solutions are as follows:
>
>  Gangster in a bus (4)
>    → G inside BUS = BU(G)S
>
>  Opposite of writing everything twice about object oriented programming (6)
>    → [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) around [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) = `DROOPY`
>
>  Iron fifty nine (5)
>    → FE + LIX = `FELIX`
>
>  Woman that is five empty liters (6)
>    → F + IE + V + EL = `FIEVEL`
>
>  Red flag I mixed up (8)
>    → REDFLAGI anagram = `GARFIELD`
>
>  Channel Island has the queen instead of Stack Exchange (5)
>    → JERSEY with SE changed to [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.) = `JERRY`
>
>  Electroacoustic transducer and lock opener (6)
>    → MIC + KEY = `MICKEY`
>
>  Nickel in a quarry (6)
>    → NI inside MINE = `MINNIE`
>
>  A poem about me (4)
>    → ODE around I = `ODIE`
>
>  Oscar followed Lily’s cousin back without me (5)
>    → O after TULIP reversed, minus I = `PLUTO`
>
>  Err; go wrong (5)
>    → ERRGO anagram  = `ROGER`
>
>  At first I protected princesses in heaven (6)
>    → initials of "I Protected Princesses" in SKY = `SKIPPY`
>
>  Crazy, nosy OP (6)
>    → NOSYOP anagram = `SNOOPY`
>
>  He messed with Trump (7)
>    → HE+TRUMP anagram = `THUMPER`
>
>  Odd things go eery (6)
>    → Every other letter of "things go eery" = `TIGGER`
>
>  Beginning of the other mother (3)
>    → First letters of "The Other Mother" = `TOM`

These answers

> can be divided into four categories, as a connecting wall:
>
>  **Animated cats:** FELIX, GARFIELD, TIGGER, TOM
>  **Animated dogs:** DROOPY, ODIE, PLUTO, SNOOPY
>  **Animated mice:** FIEVEL, JERRY, MICKEY, MINNIE
>  **Animated rabbits:** BUGS, ROGER, SKIPPY, THUMPER

Comment: rot13(Zbir Qebccl gb Qbtf naq lbhe zvffvat svefg bar vf OH(T)F Ohaal! )

Comment: @Stiv Ah, thanks - fixed!